# Django - No CSRF error for posts without token

Tags: django, http, csrf, django-csrf

I'm using Django to host a React application. I added the CSRF protection middleware in Django. I tried testing it by sending a http post with Postman, without the x-csrftoken in the header. To my surprise, I did not get a 403, but I was able to get data without the x-csrftoken. How is this possible?
Below you find my CSRF settings. My additional Django settings are very straightforward and include CORS.

```py
...
# Cross Origin Resource Sharing Protection
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
]
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
# Cross Site Request Forgery Protection
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = []
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
]
```

Comment: Are you using DRF? What kind of authentication are you using?

Comment: Yes I'm using DRF. As a matter of a fact I use the token authentication from DRF.

Comment: Look at answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using anything other than SessionAuthentication [CSRF will be disabled](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/6104#issuecomment-410238487). In [the docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#sessionauthentication).